# Java Swing GridBagLayout выравнивание компонентов внутри ячейки и нижние отступы

Tags: java, swing, layoutmanager

Необходимо произвести выравнивание метки и текстового поля по левому краю, чтобы текстовое поле растягивалось вместе с ячейкой и оставалась под меткой. Также нужно избавиться от больших отступов между ячейками по вертикали

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        JPanel panel;
        JTextField jtf;
        JLabel lbl;

        constraints.weightx = 1.0;
        constraints.weighty = 1.0;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        constraints.ipadx = 3;
        constraints.ipady = 3;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                panel = new JPanel();
                lbl = new JLabel("Label "+i, SwingConstants.LEFT);
                jtf = new JTextField();

                jtf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(170, 25));
                panel.add(lbl);
                panel.add(jtf);
                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(170, 51));
                panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 1));
                constraints.gridx = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
                constraints.gridy = i;

                jPanel4.add(panel, constraints);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы надпись всегда оставалась над текстовым полем, вам нужно поменять layout внутренних панелей. По-умолчанию там `FlowLayout`, который выстраивает компоненты в линию, и переносит на новую строку, только если они не влезают. Можно взять `BoxLayout` или `BorderLayout`:

```
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout( new BoxLayout( panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ) );
            JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Label "+row, SwingConstants.LEFT);
            JTextField jtf = new JTextField();

            lbl.setAlignmentX( 0.5f ); // метка будет отцентрована
            panel.add(lbl);

            jtf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(170, 25));
            panel.add(jtf);

            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(170, 51));
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 1));
```

Чтобы убрать отступы между строками, нужно решить, что с ними делать. Если нужно растянуть строки по вертикали, то в `constraints` должен быть одинаковый вертикальный вес у всех строк и растяжение по обеим осям:

```
constraints.weighty = 1.0;
constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

В этом случае начнет растягиваться текстовое поле, чтобы этого избежать, можно задать ему максимальный размер: `jtf.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, 25));`

Если нужно собрать строки в верхней части формы, можно убрать им вертикальный вес, оставить растяжение по ширине, а после всех циклов вставить невидимый пустой компонент с ненулевым вертикальным весом. Этот компонент займет все свободное пространство.

```
    for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
            /* ... */
            jPanel4.add(panel, constraints);
        }
    }
    constraints.gridy = 100500;
    constraints.weighty = 100500f;
    jPanel4.add( new JPanel(), constraints );
```

---

Полный код:

```
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.weightx = 1.0;
    constraints.weighty = 0.0;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    constraints.ipadx = 3;
    constraints.ipady = 3;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            // BoxLayout с вертикальным расположением
            panel.setLayout( new BoxLayout( panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS ) );

            JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Label "+row, SwingConstants.LEADING );
            // выравнивание компонента зависит не только от его собственного
            //   alignmentX, но и от alignmentX других компонентов
            //   поэтому надо задавать и для textfield тоже
            lbl.setAlignmentX( Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT );
            panel.add(lbl);

            JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
            jtf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(170, 25));
            // BoxLayout учитывает MaximumSize, если не указать
            //   то textfield растянется в высоту
            jtf.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 25));
            jtf.setAlignmentX( Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT );
            panel.add(jtf);

            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 1));

            constraints.gridx = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
            constraints.gridy = row;

            jPanel4.add(panel, constraints);
        }
    }
    // заполняем последний ряд GridBagLayout, нужно убрать отступы,
    //   что бы не было заметно при минимальной высоте панели
    constraints.gridy = 100500;
    constraints.weighty = 100500f;
    constraints.ipadx = 0;
    constraints.ipady = 0;
    constraints.insets = new Insets( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    // Box.createVerticalStrut(0) создает невидимый компонент нулевой высоты
    jPanel4.add( Box.createVerticalStrut( 0 ), constraints );
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Только почему то все ячейки, начиная со второго ряда остались растянутыми по вертикали. На первом ряду всё хорошо. И метку тоже надо привязать к левому бордеру.

Comment: @murash добавил ваш код со своими правками

Comment: Всё, работает, спасибо!